# No gradients provided for any variable in my ustom loss function

Tags: tensorflow, path, intersect, loss

I have the following custom error function that indicates me how close I am on 10 variables :

```
def custom__error(y_true, y_pred):
    yt = tf.nn.softmax( y_true )
    bt = 1 + tf.argsort(yt,axis=-1,direction='DESCENDING',stable=False,name=None)
    ct = tf.keras.backend.eval(bt)
    dt = ct[:,:10]

    yp = tf.nn.softmax( y_pred )    
    bp = 1 + tf.argsort(yp,axis=-1,direction='DESCENDING',stable=False,name=None)
    cp = tf.keras.backend.eval(bp)
    dp = cp[:,:10]

    ii = tf.sets.intersection(dt, dp)
    result = len(ii.values)/y_true.shape[1]
    tf.print(10-result)
    return result
```

I want to use it for my loss function so I wrote :

```
def custom_lossss(y_true, y_pred, coef1, coef2,coef3,coef4):
    yt = tf.nn.softmax( y_true )
    bt = 1 + tf.argsort(yt,axis=-1,direction='DESCENDING',stable=False,name=None)
    ct = tf.keras.backend.eval(bt)
    dt = ct[:,:10]

    yp = tf.nn.softmax( y_pred )    
    bp = 1 + tf.argsort(yp,axis=-1,direction='DESCENDING',stable=False,name=None)
    cp = tf.keras.backend.eval(bp)
    dp = cp[:,:10]

    ii = tf.sets.intersection(dt, dp)
    iivl = tf.size(ii.values)
    trdv = tf.divide(iivl,tf.size(y_true))

    return trdv
```

But I get the error : **No gradients provided for any variable**
I don't see where the path is broken !!
Do you have any clues ?

Comment: In fact it seems that sorting can't be used inside loss function.

Comment: have you found any solutions yet?